# jQuery loop to change bg image is making requests for already loaded images all over again

Tags: jquery, css

I have section of a website change it's bg image with jquery.
I target the css inside a loop

```
image.fadeOut(800, function () {
    image.css('background-image', 'url(img/' + images [i++] +')');
    image.fadeIn(800);
});
    if(i == images.length)
    i = 0;
```

I go to Chrome's dev tools and see that it is making requests for the bg images even though they were already shown.

From the Size Content column says "(from cache)".

**Will this hurt performance on the page at some point?
Or is it just calling the already loaded image?**

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3265034/1523400). You can also define a function to auto set the images array.

Comment: The function I'm using is working fine, What I need to know is if the requests being made after loop restarts.

Comment: As you've stated, the overhead is on the browser to see if the images are cached. Considering how prevalent it is to pre-load images, you're probably fine. How many images are you fading in/out? How large?

Comment: You can check the .complete attribute, it should mostly be true if the image is cached.

Comment: There are just 4 images ~150kb each

I have some concern since I went to dev Tools and all I see is this long list of requests... 
Since I want this for mobile as well, I want to know if this is really from cache.

Comment: You can preload image to put it in cache using a loading pixel.

Comment: @Jazzvel - In a perfect world, I'd say "oh yes, they're pulled from the cache!", but considering the state of mobile...you never know ;) I did look into this a bit and found that if you preload the image and reference the image object, it does not make a network request. Here are two fiddles demonstrating: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6V4Dw/show/ (original, which makes multi-requests) and http://fiddle.jshell.net/6V4Dw/1/show/ (preloaded) - FYI for others - the best way to repo the long network req. list is to view in incognito.

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. Could you please post this as an answer? With the for loop to preload the images!
I made some changes to your code and it works as expected! No more extra requests! :D
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious and looked into this question a bit more and was able to reproduce the issue where the browser would make n-number of request for the images (although, as you noticed - it was inconsistent...there were times it would only make 4 requests, and other times where it would make 12 and stop... and other times it would just keep going...)

Looking into `pre-loading`, I found that if you preloaded an image object and reference that, the browser would not make additional requests.

Here's a fiddle demonstrating: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6V4Dw/1/show/

Thanks!